# LARAVEL: How to display all the same user type as the one currently logged in on a <table>?

Tags: html, laravel

Im new to laravel and im currently trying to get all the same user types as the one currently logged in to display on a table. For example, if a teacher is logged in, then all the other teacher type users must be listed on the table, only the teachers, no students no etc. I am currently using the make auth thingy.

table code

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead class="bg-danger">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->user_type }}</td>
          <td style="width: 13%">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Edit') }}</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Delete') }}</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Controller code

```
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('users.index')->with([
            'contentheader' => 'Users',
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

migration code

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username', 20)->unique();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('user_type',['teacher','student']);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get only the particular user type instead of all user like this

```
 $users = User::where('user_type','=', auth()->user()->user_type)->get();
```

This `auth()->user()->user_type` will give you the type of user which is currently logged in, using that you can filter out users.

Comment: Trying to get property 'user_type' of non-object i got this

Comment: What is the column name where you specify the user type? According to your migration I can see that it is user_type, if it the same it will work.

Comment: oh, I forget the `->get()` in the query, check the answer now

Comment: its user_type, i have no idea why it producing an error

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'user_type' of non-object

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in? what does `dd(auth()->user());` return?

Comment: ohhh it works now and you guessed it im not logged in. im so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Add middleware Auth in your route first,
as

```
Route::get('your route and related method')->middleware('auth');
```

And run query in your controller Method as,

```
use Auth;//don't forgot to add this
 public function index()
    {
       if(Auth::check())
       {
        $users = User::where('user_type',Auth::user()->user_type)->where('id','!=',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        return view('users.index')->with([         
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have `Auth` you can check the logged in user type from it.

```
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where('user_type',Auth::user()->user_type)->get();

        return view('users.index')->with([
            'contentheader' => 'Users',
            'users' => $users,
        ]);
    }
```

This will fetch the same type of user as of currently logged in user. For teacher it will fetch all teachers  and for student it will fetch all students.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found

Comment: You can check my answer which will not cause this issue.

Comment: you have to use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` at the use section of the controller.

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'user_type' of non-object

Comment: are you surely logged in??

Answer (score 1):

In your Controller change `$users = User::all();` with following,

```
$users = User::where('user_type', Auth::user()->user_type)->get();
```

Comment: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'user_type' of non-object